# Sharing files from google cloud storage to GAE

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have one Django application running GAE.The application uses content folder which contains images and html snippets.The content folder was uploaded in google cloud storage.I would like to render a image in static file  using img tag.For using img tag I want to know the url of that image.I have seen that when we set the permission to share publicly it will give us a url.But I don't want to share that files publicly.If I share an another application can use my files.I don't want that.I there any way to do that with out log in a user

Answer (score 0):

Sharing it publicly is the best way to go.

You could also [base64 encode](http://codedependant.net/blog/posts/20-3/increase-site-performance-with-django-base64-encod/) the image data when you render out the template, which means the url of the image will not be shown to the public on your page. Then you can obfuscate the image names in the GCS. This way it's still public but hard to reach.